# Stacking Different Data With The Same Field Names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am working with three tables in MySQL, one from Company A (18,000 records), one from Company B (145,000 records) and one from Company C (8,000 records). Each table has unique data, but has the same exact field names. I need to join all three tables together to stack the data on top of each other, so the data is combined, so there would be 8+18+145= 171,000 records in total in one table. Can anyone help me out with the SQL Query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, 'Company A'
  FROM table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.a, t2.b, 'Company B'
  FROM table2 t2
UNIONALL
SELECT t3.a, t3.b, 'Company C'
  FROM table3 t3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a `union all` query:

```
select t.*
from ((select 'A' as which, A.* from A) union all
      (select 'B' as which, B.* from B) union all
      (select 'C' as which, C.* from C)
     ) t
```

This assumes the field names are in the same order and have compatible types.  It is good practice to list all the field names separately in each subquery.